# Create Keycloak user via rest api without bear token

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

Currently, I tried to find a way to create a keycloak user and just found cases that need to have an admin access token (mean that need to log in with admin account first).

My client-server(java) system using keycloak for authentication and need a function for new user able to register a new account on the client.

Is there any way to create a user via the rest API and no need an admin token? If not, should I store the keycloak admin username/password to my server-side and using it to register a user (with this case, please share me the way to secure admin credentials if you know)?